# Delete children with @OneToMany

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I have some classes:

[image]

Picture:

```
public class Picture {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "picture", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<AdditionalPictureInfo> additionalInfo = new HashSet<>();

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "picture", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<Comment> comments = new HashSet<>();

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "picture", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<URLScanResult> urlScanResults = new HashSet<>();
```

Comment:

```
public class Comment {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "picture_id")
private Picture picture;
```

AdditionalInfo:

```
public class AdditionalPictureInfo {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "picture_id")
private Picture picture;
```

URLScanResult:

```
public class URLScanResult {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "scan_id")
private URLScan urlScan;
```

URLScan:

```
public class URLScan {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;


@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "urlScan", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<URLScanResult> results = new HashSet<>();
```

In my use case, I want to delete Picture and also associated comments, additional info, and url scans results. Everything works with comments and additional Info. If picture is referenced from URLScanResults, then there is following exception:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Referential integrity constraint violation: "FK1AA1C1T58EMNCAAG78CVTYMFH: PUBLIC.URL_SCAN_RESULT FOREIGN KEY(PICTURE_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.PICTURE(ID) (3)"; SQL statement:
```

I understand the exception but I do not known why before deleting Picture, associated URLScanResult entities are not deleted. I suppose that is a problem that URLScanResult is also associated with URLScan. Comments and additional info are deleted. Can someone explain why this happens and how to fix it?

I am using spring boot and hibernate.

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Thanks for comments. For some clarification:

```
Hibernate: delete from additional_picture_info where id=?
Hibernate: delete from comment where id=?
Hibernate: delete from picture where id=?
2018-11-30 20:21:56.062  WARN 14251 --- [io-10080-exec-8] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23503
2018-11-30 20:21:56.062 ERROR 14251 --- [io-10080-exec-8] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: update or delete on table "picture" violates foreign key constraint "fk1aa1c1t58emncaag78cvtymfh" on table "url_scan_result"
Detail: Key (id)=(1) is still referenced from table "url_scan_result".
```

Look for sql logs. Comments and Additional Info are deleted before Picture delete. I know that I can first delete each URLScanResult manually but why it works with Comments and Additional Info automatically?

Comment: The error is saying that your url_scan_result table has a reference to the picture table which is violating the constraint on the delete.  You cannot remove the picture if another table is holding a reference to it.  The other items are not deleting because they are all ran in a single transaction.  Everything has to succeed otherwise a rollback is performed and nothing gets deleted.

Comment: Its constrain violation on the database (not JPA) - remove parent entity first (or at least unlink it) and you will be good.

Comment: @PaulZepernick normally I would agreed, but OP states that its works for comments and it seems there is the same kind of relation configureation for those, so its kind of weird (made me delete my answer ;().

Comment: Why don't you cascade also from UrlScanResult to UrlScan?. Your url scan should be also deleted.

Comment: @SebastianSzwaczyk that is the reason I rather delete whole tree by myself - but thats just me and it could be troublesome if dependency graph is large. But thats not your case.

Comment: @Antoniossss I would be baffled if it was deleting some of Lists on the many side even with the exception.  I thought maybe the OP was saying it deleted okay if there was not a record on url_scan_result.  Maybe additional clarification is needed.

Comment: @PaulZepernick as for my understanding its like - if there is URLScanResult - violation occures, otherwise it works. What just came to my mind is that maybe OP think it works because there are no eg comments after all - thus his stance.

Comment: @SebastianSzwaczyk are you sure that some comments gets delated (just came to my mind that this might be not true as comments might not exist) The same applies to additional picture

Comment: @pdem - I don't want to delete URLScan becouse there can be linked more URLScanResults with different pictures and I want them to stay in db.